# Windows equivalent of a MacOS.app with a contents directory

Tags: windows, executable, pyinstaller

This may sound like I'm just looking for a .exe file, but I'm not all that familiar with windows. I have been using [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to turn my apps into binaries. My app relies on a lot data directories and third party binaries that I package within the same directory as the executable binary. For Mac, this makes things easy because the user only has to click on MyApp.app inside the applications directory which is like a link to MyApp.app/Contents/MacOs/MyApp. This way MyApp never has to be touched and is all bundled together with the data directories (also loaded inside of MyApp.app/Contents/MacOs/).

However, I can't really find a windows equivalent. While Pyinstaller can create a directory with my data directories and executable inside of it, if the user ever moves the .exe file inside the directory, the app will never work (because it loses its relative location to the data directories). Is there such a thing that can package this directory like on MacOS so the user just has to click on a single .exe file that links to the .exe inside the directory packaged within it? That way we can just pass around one directory. Like a Mac.app?

Comment: I'm not really looking for an alias, something I can just give the user and they can click on and thats it!

Answer (score 1):

Win32 apps store data within the executable file as *resources*, which allows the single file solution, but they can't be accessed using normal file APIs, there are a separate set of functions for resource handling.  (This implies that resources aren't so useful for things that absolutely have to be files, like images of helper executables.)

Win32 also has [*alternate data streams*](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx), which are more similar to what you're used to with .app packages, separating a local identifier from the actual filename by `$DATA:`.  But those only work on NTFS, get lost by many file management applications, never have been very popular, and are now effectively deprecated by Microsoft (by preventing access from Windows Store apps).

Comment: So the executable within my data directory would then need to be operated on by these separate set of functions to create a new .exe? If so, can you point me towards this separate set of functions?

Comment: @jwillis0720: Injection of the resources is normally done by the resource compiler RC.EXE, although the resource access API is not read-only.  Here are the functions for accessing Win32 resources: [Resource Functions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902.aspx)